# In what situation the on event can fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've a big source file so not sharing it here but the problem that I'm having is that I'm unable to add the click event using the following code:

```
$(document).on('click','#test' + testId , function(e){
            console.log('I was clicked');
        });
```

If I use this code on separate file, it works but in my actual source, I'm unable to dispatch the event :( What might be the reason?

Comment: The reason might be that the element you're hoping to identify with `'#test' + testId` doesn't actually exist. Your ability to guess at the answer should be better than mine, though, since you have the advantage of being able to see all of the relevant parts of the Javascript and HTML.

Comment: I attached the event to the document, not the element, so element doesn't need to exist at the time of event dispatch

Comment: My point was that the element may **never** exist, and the id of the element you're clicking on isn't the same as the id specified in the selector using the variable `testId`.

Comment: Instead of just saying you're "unable" to do something, _describe behaviours_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the code in setTimeout method and that solved the problem. I was not expecting this because I was attaching the event to the body not the element. The element didn't really exist at the time of attaching event to the body so the event was not being dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

You document must be loaded or the element `'#test' + testId` must exist at least.

```
<body onload="init()">
```

And here your javascript function:

```
function init() 
{
    $(document).on('click','#test' + testId , function(e){
        console.log('I was clicked');
    });
}
```

Comment: he attached the event to the `document`, not to the `'#test' + testId`. It's not it

Comment: Oh god. Don't do that. Javascript in HTML properties is ghastly!

Answer (score 0):

> What might be the reason?

1. That `#test + testId` element doesn't exist.
2. Other event handler stops the propagation with `e.stopPropagation()` or `return false;`

Comment: I don't have e.preventPropagation(); or return false in my code. Is any of these statements exist in jquery events? Like I've another same on('click' event, may that stop the propagation?

Comment: @wasimbhalli. only if it returns false. try put an alert with `'#test' + testId` make sure that element is really there.

Comment: Yes, I create the element, and I've tested and it exists. By the way, Isn't `on` method a replacement for live? So it should also work if the element is added later to the DOM?

Comment: If I add the event in firebug console, it attaches successfully :s